Conditional formula to show/hide a column based on if two dates cross over a fiscal year
I don't know if it possible to do this in the base sharepoint form builder, but I am trying to get a column to show up if 2 supplied dates cross over the end of the fiscal year. I don't want to hard code that date and instead am trying to compare the months and years from the entered dates. I have a formula like that that works in excel and when I try to do something similar in the conditional formula for the column, I can't get it to work.
=IF(YEAR(A1)=YEAR(A2),IF(MONTH(A1)<7,IF(MONTH(A2)>6,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE),IF(MONTH(A2)>6,TRUE,IF(MONTH(A1)<7,TRUE,FALSE)))


Fiscal year can be different for every country. Here's an example with June 30:
=IF(AND(YEAR([Start Date])=YEAR([End Date]),MONTH([Start Date])<7,MONTH([End Date])>6), TRUE, 
IF(AND(YEAR([Start Date])<>YEAR([End Date]),OR(MONTH([Start Date])<7,MONTH([End Date])>6)), TRUE, FALSE))

